# Is Likessale a scam?

Tags: mountain-bike

I'm looking at a [bike for sale](https://www.likessale.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=1&path=1_2) on Likessale. It seems way too good to be true, based on a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS713US714&biw=1920&bih=969&tbm=shop&ei=yu1EXKutG4bI_QaqyYSQBA&q=Diamond%20Release%205%20C&oq=Diamond%20Release%205%20C&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5260.6700.0.7517.8.7.0.0.0.0.186.594.2j3.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.1.104...0i13k1.0.AfXZDxKv7aQ#spd=13111342335810783757) for prices for the same bike. Has anyone bought a bike here or can verify whether or not this is a scam?

I looked up [likessale.com on WHOIS](https://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=likessale.com), and it appeared to be registered only a week ago. It seems fishy that there are reviews from before that.

Comment: I think there has been one "is this a scam" question in the history of stackoverflow where it wasn't.

Comment: Nevertheless, I think this question and upcoming answer provides value to this community. It documents this particular instance and allows us to share information.

Comment: here's the important part of the whois record in DNS.         Creation Date: 2019-01-14T06:25:44Z

Comment: @ojs I'd love to hear what that was, I think that would also provide useful information

Comment: @pateksan can't find it now, but it was someone who was contacted by an unknown lawyer about inheritance from distant relative. The conclusion was that if every detail checks out, it could be real.

Comment: @pateksan it was on money.se but I can't find it with a quick search

Comment: I have informed Diamondback that someone is using their portfolio to scam people. Can confirm; it's fraud.

Comment: Engrish! https://www.likessale.com/About-Us

Comment: Contact page https://www.likessale.com/contact-us gives a different domain, topservice4u.com, which whois says was registered in October 2018 by some outfit in West Yorkshire.

Comment: If they ever send you a bike please upload a photo. I'd be interested to see what 89 $ will buy you :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm confident to call it a scam.

The same bike is on Amazon for $2162 to $3856 USD.

[https://www.amazon.com/Diamondback-Bicycles-Podium-Vitesse-Carbon/dp/B01HHQ1BWA/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_200_t_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HHQ1BWA)

Manufacturer gives it a MSRP of $3700 USD.
 
To expect to pay 5% of that price is **MASSIVELY suspicious**.

---

Also notice the site lists MTB-style frame sizes (Small-15.5/Medium-17/Large-19/XL-21), where the bike is built in metric sizes (XS 50; S 52; M 54; L 56; XL 58cm)

---

I see the word "diamondback" never appears on the remote web site at all in text - it only appears on the bike photos which appear to be lifted from standard advertising materials.

**TL;DR** Yes its a scam.  Send your money at your risk.  If you ever do get a bike delivered, it will be an inferior knockoff product.

Just don't.

Comment: Also consider viewing some useful forgery/counterfeit videos like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYejuaEHzV8  and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qC7GeLrmYo

Answer (score 4):

Don't give money to likesale.com.

I made a purchase on 18 January 2019 and I should've done some research before. I also wondered how they could have reviews posted from september when the site is only a week old.

I've emailed the website and even sent an email to the owner email address provided through the domain info. Haven't received any info, and will post any new info I find out.

I'm pissed and have to decided to spend some time giving this particular scam as much hell as I can.

Comment: The site owner doesn't have any reason to answer to email. They already have your money and this should be reported directly to police. If you paid with credit card, the credit card company too.

Comment: Paying with _any_ card, you should talk to your bank.

Comment: Contact your bank and do a Charge back immediately.  Now.  Then discuss with your bank what to do about your card - immediately invalidating it would be a very good idea.

Comment: Fun fact: If you live in the United States, the Secret Service actually investigates fraud like this quite thoroughly. Interestingly enough, they have two jobs - protect the president (etc), and investigate fraud.

Answer (score 3):

I also made an online purchase two weeks ago and I've not received the product or shipping information to track the delivery.  I've not received replies to my emails and I don't have telephone numbers. If somebody knows what I can do, please tell me.

---

<sup>This post was originally made in Spanish, as follows.</sup>

<sup>Yo tambien he realizado una compra en linea hace dos semanas atras y no he recibido ni el producto, ni la cadena de envoi para rastreo del producto ni mucho menos recibo mensajes de contestacion al correo que mencionan, no tienen numeros telefonicos, si alguien sabe que puedo hacer por favor hacermelo saber.</sup>

Comment: Talk to your bank or credit card company. Tell them you paid for the goods, they haven't arrived and that you believe it is a scam. They should give you your money back.